# Susanna NEAL in Lincolnshire baptized 1774 - who did she marry?

Tags: marriage-records, lincolnshire

On 7-Jan-1774, Susanna Neal was baptized in Huttoft, Lincolnshire, England. Her parents were listed as Willm Neal and Ann.

On 15-May-1791, in South Ormsby (11 miles from Huttoft), Susannah Neal married Nathaniel Bradley. There are seven children baptized (in South Ormsby, Scrembly, and Candelsby) with parents Nathaniel Bradley and Susannah between 1792 and 1807.

On 17-May-1795, Elizabeth Neal, "Natural daughter of Susannah Neal" was baptized in Bilsby. No father was mentioned in the record.

Onn 8-Oct-1801, in Bilsby (3 miles from Huttoft), Susanna Neal married John Barker.

On 25-May-1802, "Susanna, wife of John Barker", was buried in Huttoft.

On 31-Jan-1810, in Huttoft, Susanna Neal married Charles Lindsey.

In the 1841 census, there is a Charles (age 50) & Susana Lindsey (age 50) living in Strubby (about 2 miles from Huttoft) with 8 kids (but I haven't looked for their births/baptisms yet)

---

It seems clear to me that these are three different SUSAN-XXX NEALs.

I'm trying to figure out which one of them is the one that was baptized in 1774.
Any suggestions?

Comment: I found a baptism record for 'Susana Neal' in Huttoft on 14-Jan-1789. Parents Jno Neal and Elizabeth. That's a good candidate for the one who married in 1810.

Comment: The first line of your question says 1774, but the title and last line say 1773. Are both 1773 and 1774 in play, or is one of these a typo?

Comment: Typo. Fixed. 3 more chars.